Electron App Preventing Network Connections: Still Seeing Unexpected Domains
I'm developing an Electron application using Vite and trying to ensure that it does not make any external network connections. My goal is to have an app that works completely offline, without any communication to external servers or domains. However, when I analyze the app using tools like VirusTotal or MetaDefender, I keep seeing connections to unexpected domains, such as business.bing.com, azureedge.net, and other similar ones.
What I've Tried:
Blocking Network Requests: I've added a webRequest.onBeforeRequest handler in my main.js to block any URL that doesn't start with localhost or file://.
mainWindow.webContents.session.webRequest.onBeforeRequest((details, callback) => {
  if (details.url.startsWith('http://localhost') || details.url.startsWith('file://')) {
    callback({ cancel: false }); // Allow local requests
  } else {
    console.log('Blocked:', details.url);
    callback({ cancel: true }); // Block all other requests
  }
});

Disabling DevTools: I suspect some of these connections might be related to the use of Chromium DevTools, as I see URLs like chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com in my logs. I've tried disabling DevTools:
mainWindow.webContents.on('devtools-opened', () => {
  mainWindow.webContents.closeDevTools();
});

Sandbox and Context Isolation: I have sandboxing disabled and context isolation enabled in webPreferences:
webPreferences: {
  contextIsolation: true,
  nodeIntegration: false,
  sandbox: false,
  preload: join(__dirname, '../preload/index.js')
}

Despite these efforts, the analysis still shows connections to domains that I do not recognize or intend to connect to. I also noticed that when I open DevTools, there are references to external resources.
My Questions:
How can I ensure that my Electron app is truly offline? Are there any settings or techniques I am missing?
Could these external connections be caused by something within Electron or Vite? How do I identify and stop all unwanted connections?
Is there a way to confirm if these domains are being accessed by built-in Chromium features or any specific libraries?
Any guidance or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
